# Quick and easy power management software for Win 7

Tags: windows-7, power-management

Probably one of the most disappointing things for windows 7 is the power management.

It's clunky, there's no quick option to kind of just go "do not sleep" or "sleep at this time" or "sleep in n hours".

Is there any software (freeware) that just has these features up front and as easy to use as say hitting the Sleep timer on your TV or alarm radio?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a seperate program, you might want to try [Sleep Timer](http://www.mydigitallife.info/schedule-windows-shutdown-with-vista-shutdown-sleep-timer/), which works with Vista and 7.

Otherwise, you can create a scheduled task by:

- Open Task Scheduler and create a new task with a name like "Sleep at x time"
- Set the trigger to be daily
- The start time should be when you want the PC to sleep, and set it to recur every day.
- The action should be set to start a program, and point to: C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe with arguments powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
- Before finishing, click on "Open Properties when I click Finish".
- In that new window, select “Run whether user is logged on or not” and check “Run with highest privileges”